# HTML5 IFRAME Sandbox with Links in content of IFRAME

Tags: html, iframe, sandbox

For me allow-top-navigation is not working when used in sandbox attribute. The link is for different domain. Allow-Forms works for me. Link even does not respond. It does not do anything. 
So, also I am wondering whether a link is more a security concern than form submit?

sandbox="allow-forms allow-top-navigation"

Is there a way to make link works and open in top navigation while using sandbox? I tried with seamless attribute but no use.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `allow-top-navigation` flag will allow you to use either `<a ... target="_top">` links or `window.top.location` inside of the sandboxed `iframe`.

Is it possible that you're trying to adjust the top window's location via JavaScript? If so, you'll also need to allow script inside the sandbox via the `allow-scripts` sandbox flag: `<iframe ... sandbox="allow-forms allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"></iframe>` works for me.

Comment: "...  trying to adjust the top window's location..." - top window means where the IFRAME element is used!  I have not checked that.

Comment: If the iframe contains an `<a href="..." target="_blank">` then you'll need the `allow-popups` permission.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe